# What if David was fed?

Tags: tanach

I came across a lecture by Rabbi Amnon Yitzchak, and he stated that Jonathan, as much as he loved David as a best friend, should have fed him when he shot the arrows past him to signify he should leave.

He goes on to explain that because of this mistake, David being hungry went to eat in Nov, which led to Saul's decree, and therefore Jonathan died in war because of that mistake.

I wanted to know if there are **any sources for this**, he didn't mention it but it seems legit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sanhedrin 104A](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.104a.5?lang=bi):

> ושגגתה עולה זדון דאמר רב יהודה אמר רב אלמלי הלווהו יהונתן לדוד שתי ככרות לחם לא נהרגה נוב עיר הכהנים ולא נטרד דואג האדמי ולא נהרג שאול ושלשת בניו

> And the fact that an unwitting transgression with regard to it is at times considered an intentional transgression is derived as Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: Had Jonathan lent David two loaves of bread when he was fleeing Saul, David would not have sought sustenance from the priests in Nov. The residents of Nov, city of the priests, would not have been killed, and Doeg the Edomite would not have been banished from the World-to-Come, and Saul and his three sons would not have been killed as punishment for that massacre

Comment: Wow thank you! So he unwittingly created the possibility for Doeg to lose Olam Haba, does Jonathan have Olam Haba?

Comment: I believe so. I don’t think he counted amongst those who don’t have

Comment: See Yerushalmi Pesachim 6:1  where Yehonasan is listed as one of three people who abandoned their crowns in This World and inherited the life of the World to Come.

Comment: He just didn't think of it? How did it happen?